# p5.js code doesn't run as expected in web editor

Tags: javascript, html, api, iframe, p5.js

I have already finished my project of building a p5.js weather forecast using OpenWeather's api. The code runs perfectly when I open the index.html file. Why doesn't it display the weather when I run it on the web editor or use it as an iframe on my blog?

[github gist](https://gist.github.com/VlatkoStojkoski/e9fd131e232a0908094f7b54ab3c6417)

[project](https://editor.p5js.org/mirorredturtle@gmail.com/sketches/rJQfFcX_m)

Comment: The first thing you should do is check out the [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) to see your errors. That will show you that you're missing library files. See ashish's answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have libraries folder uploaded which contains p5 and other libraries.

update your index.html to include those libraries

these lines

```
<script src="libraries/p5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="libraries/p5.dom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="libraries/p5.sound.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```